# Slow query grouping on blob column

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, query-optimization, explain

I'm using the following query to extract the frequent short values from a `mediumblob` column :

```sql
select bytes, count(*) as n
from pr_value
where bytes is not null && length(bytes)<11 and variable_id=5783
group by bytes order by n desc limit 10;
```

The problem I have is that this query takes too much time (about 10 seconds with less than 1 million records) :

```sql
mysql> select bytes, count(*) as n from pr_value where bytes is not null && length(bytes)<11 and variable_id=5783 group by bytes order by n desc limit 10;
+-------+----+
| bytes | n  |
+-------+----+
| 32    | 21 |
| 27    | 20 |
| 52    | 20 |
| 23    | 19 |
| 25    | 19 |
| 26    | 19 |
| 28    | 19 |
| 29    | 19 |
| 30    | 19 |
| 31    | 19 |
+-------+----+
```

The table is as follows (unrelated columns not shown) :

```sql
mysql> describe pr_value;
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| product_id  | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| variable_id | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| author_id   | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| bytes       | mediumblob    | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

The type is mediumblob because most values are big. Less than 10% are short as the ones I'm looking for with this specific query.

I have the following indexes :

```sql
mysql> show index from pr_value;
+----------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table    | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+----------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| pr_value |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | product_id  | A         |        8961 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| pr_value |          0 | PRIMARY  |            2 | variable_id | A         |      842402 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| pr_value |          0 | PRIMARY  |            3 | author_id   | A         |      842402 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| pr_value |          1 | bytes    |            1 | bytes       | A         |      842402 |       10 | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| pr_value |          1 | bytes    |            2 | variable_id | A         |      842402 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+----------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

MySQL explains my query like this :

```sql
mysql> explain select bytes, count(*) as n from pr_value where bytes is not null && length(bytes)<11 and variable_id=5783 group by bytes order by n desc limit 10; 
+----+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+-------+---------+------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table    | type  | possible_keys | key   | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+-------+---------+------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | pr_value | range | bytes         | bytes | 13      | NULL | 421201 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+-------+---------+------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Note that the condition on the length of the bytes column can be removed without changing the duration.

What can I do to make this query fast ?

Of course i'd prefer not to have to add columns.

Comment: Are there calculated columns in mySql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your index on (bytes, variable_id) is not very smart. If you always have a variable_id clause in your queries you should add index with variable_id first :

`(variable_id, bytes)`

It depend on how discriminant variable_id is. But it sould help.

Another tip is to add a new indexed column with the result of "length(bytes)<11" :

```
update pr_value set small = length(bytes)<11;
```

Add a new index with (small,variable_id).

Comment: Your indexing suggestion seems very good. I'll be back with comments (and/or upvote+accept) as soon as I have tested on my servers.

Comment: In fact it works very well on my dev server (the duration drops to 0.07s which is acceptable for my application) but not on one of my servers (windows) where it is about 45 seconds and longer than without index. Do you have ideas about what could cause this ? A server parameter ?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea why your server behaviour is not the same. Did you check with explain that the index is actually in use?

Comment: Yes. I suspect a problem on this server. As you gave me an important tip (ordering the columns in the index), I'll accept your answer now. Thanks and welcome to SO ;)

Answer (score 1):

Why are you GROUP BY'ing the blob column? I'd imagine that's the bottleneck as then the Query actually does a compare against all blob columns to each other. Is it because you want unique values for the BLOB? I think the DISTINCT keyword might perform better than the GROUP BY.

Comment: This should really be a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: It's because I want to get the 10 most common values. So I group and order by the number. Do you see another way to do it ?

Comment: SELECT **DISTINCT** bytes LIMIT 10;
The GROUP BY keyword and DISTINCT keyword behave slightly differently. GROUP BY is for collation/summation. For uniqueness, DISTINCT performs better because it filters results post-join.

Comment: I don't get it. What's your suggested query to get the 10 **most frequent** values along with the related number of records ?